# R plots short lines instead of dots

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to draw a line plot with the following code:

```
temp = data.frame(...) // some data here
plot(temp$hour, temp$freq, type="p", main="some text", xlab="x label", ylab="y label")
```

and the value of `temp` is something like:

```
    hour   freq
1     00    593
2     01    629
3     02    726
       .
       .
       .
23    22    719
24    23    612
```

and the plot is:

[image: line plot]

The values seems right, but the plot is using short lines. I tried to use different types of plot (type='l', 'o', 'b') as documentation suggested, but the plot won't change. Please help.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks for replying, I just checked, ```par('pch')```does print ```1```.

Comment: Your question isn't clear -- are you trying to *produce* a plot that looks like that or are you trying to *avoid* such a plot? The code you give can't produce that plot, but you say "here is the plot".

Comment: @JohnColeman Sorry about the confusing, the plot is what I got, and I am trying to avoid it, and plot a line plot instead.

Comment: If using RStudio, you could try to clear all plots. If it is literally true that "the plot won't change" in response to changing graphical parameters, then something is seriously wrong here. Are you even sure that you are getting new plots if they all look exactly the same?

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you for the suggestion of creating a ```[MCVE]```. By doing that, I found out where goes wrong. The data type of ```hour``` column is ```factor``` instead of ```numeric```, and by converting the data type to numeric, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

The data type of column `hour` is `factor` instead of `numeric`, to resolve this problem, the data type of `hour` column need to be converted to `numeric`.